# Softether deb package installation fails on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, package, checkinstall

I have created a new deb package from SoftEtherVPN source at https://github.com/SoftEtherVPN/SoftEtherVPN using

```
checkinstall -D make install
```

The process successfully installs the software but the resultant deb package fails to install with this error:

```
unable to create `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max.dpkg-new' (while processing `./proc/sys/kernel/threads-max'): No such file or directory
```

I am unable to find out how to fix this error.

MVCE:

```
ssh root@my_new_14.04_vps_ip
apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade
apt-get -y install git-core build-essential 
apt-get install libreadline6-dev libncurses5-dev libssl-dev
apt-get install checkinstall
git clone https://github.com/SoftEtherVPN/SoftEtherVPN.git
cd SoftEtherVPN
./configure
checkinstall -D make install
```

Comment: Are you running as root? Also try to make the directory manually...: sudo mkdir ./proc/sys/kernel/threads-max

Comment: Try the second suggestion... I don't know if it works though...

Comment: /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max exists. threads-max is an empty file but touch: cannot touch ‘threads-max.dpkg-new’: No such file or directory

Comment: That is strange... The error message though says ./proc/sys[...]. Notice the dot before the path... Or maybe the system needs to reboot? Sometimes a reboot solves things :/

Comment: Does your package contain stuff in `proc`, or is a script in the package (`postinst` etc) contain commands to create this? Looks like you are trying the former, which will not work - try the latter instead.

Comment: There is no postinstall script but there is a proc/sys/kernel/threads-max in the source which is SoftEtherVPN at https://github.com/SoftEtherVPN/SoftEtherVPN

Comment: I never tried, but I think you cannot "install" files in the `/proc` system; if you want to change the value in `/proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` you need to do something like `cat  /path/to/my/threads-max >  /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max` in a postinstall script. Do you really need to set this kernel setting on install? I think this should be left to the local admins.  In any case try to exclude the files in `/proc` from the package.

Comment: Uh, forget about my comment, it seems the source code in `SoftEtherVPN/src/Mayaqua/Unix.c` does the writing to proc.  `checkinstall` then thinks this is a file to include in the package. Does `checkinstall  --exclude /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max -D make install` help fixing this misunderstanding?

Comment: Please write this up as an answer so i can award the points. If possible, I would appreciate comment on whether this file is needed and why it's there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`proc` file system](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) exposes a simple pseudo-file interface to many Linux kernel facilities.  The `threads-max` setting, as the name suggests, controls how many threads the kernel allows to be created in the system.  The installer tries to write a suitable value to this file, but `checkinstall` assumes that the installer tries to create or overwrite an actual file in this location.  `dpkg` does not allow this, so the package you get from `checkinstall` is not compatible.

You can tell `checkinstall` to ignore this file, and perhaps add a separate `postinst` script to write this setting by other means when the package is installed, if necessary.

```
checkinstall --exclude /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max -D make install
```